# How to read hexadecimal numbers from input in C?

Tags: c, hex, c99

I want to read a hexadecimal number from the user. I use C99.

My idea was to read a char and check by the character code what hexadecimal number it could be.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char count;
    int c;
    printf("Enter hex value:\n");
    scanf("%c", &count);
    if (count >= 48 && count <= 57) {
        c = count - 48;
    }
    if (count >= 65 && count <= 70) {
        c = count - 55;
    }
    if (count >= 97 && count <= 102) {
        c = count - 87;
    }
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

But I think there should be easier ways. Because it can only read one number and not longer ones.

Is there anything that could help?

Comment: Where did you get those numbers, 48, 57, 65, and so on, from? Seriously, no textbook or instructor should have told you to use numbers like that. So I am curious why you used them. Maybe we can prevent some other students from doing that in the future. In C, character constants such as `'0'`, `'9'`, `'A'`, and so on provide the values of the characters. There is no reason to hard-code the numbers. Also, for portable code, you cannot rely on the letters being in a consecutive sequence.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I got these numbers by printing the entered character as an integer. And yes, you are right. It is not portable code at all. Comparing with characters is better than with their code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scanf with `%x`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    scanf("%x", &a);
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Output:

```
a -> 10
ff -> 255
```